# generate .mht file programmatically

Tags: c#, mhtml

Does anybody know how to generate .mht file programmatically in C#, with
embedded images in it? The thing is i have realised that .mht files
are capable of embedding images in them, and this embedded images
moves with the whole file(mht) when you change its location. And
this file can be viewed on different browsers, including IE 6.

I was told to try Data Url Scheme technique. But it couldn't work because
its not supported by other browsers. e.g IE 6.

Comment: I've been there - while its very possible to do this, even writing it yourself - don't go there. MHT is very proprietary and NOT supported by most modern browsers. I would look into alternatives first

Comment: I think the easiest way would be to save a few simple web pages as .mht with IE and see how it does this.

Comment: I tried to export .mht file on IE. It seems to implement Data Url Scheme technique. E.g if found the following code in the exported file(mht)

Comment: Content-Type: image/gif
Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
Content-Location: http://www.oakdome.com/lab/wp-content/step-two-create-new-connection.gif

R0lGODlhwgEuAfcAAAAAAIAAAACAAICAAAAAgIAAgACAgMDAwMDcwKbK8AIAAgABRwAAbQsrVQ0v
bjsARTsAcCg3Tyc6bBBVDxFWOA1wDR1pKidTFTRaMCptDyx0MQVPTA5FdxhlSw9qbzNHVS9Ocyxz
RydseVQABFkBZFNhH2BlaQcWigYWrg46kwc6qzg8lSo4tQAczgU20gg15Cc10QJFkhNMtABqngBu

Comment: @chosenOneThabs MHT is based on RFC 2557 - see answer(s) below...

Comment: The reason why i'm trying to embed image in html file
is because i'm creating a windows form application
that has to export a report with images.

Is there a way to accomplish without using commercial
libraries?

Comment: Oh i finally decided to make use of Visual studio's ReportViewer Control, because i realized that this issue was going to take me some time to solve, and i'm having a deadline. But thanks alot, at least i learned about how MHT files work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is possible and has definitely been done by others - relevant material and libraries/source code:

- [RFC 2557](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2557.txt) is the foundation of MHT format
- [VB.NET source code for generating MHT files from an URL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8268/Convert-any-URL-to-a-MHTML-archive-using-native-NE)
- [Chilkat MHT .NET library](http://www.chilkatsoft.com/MHT-DotNet.asp) (commercial)
- [ASPNetMHT](http://www.aspnetmht.com/overview.aspx) (commercial)
- [C# source code for generating MHT files from an URL](http://code.google.com/p/url2mhtml/)
- CDO.Message COM component, which exposes the [IMessage interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: I tried the above. It seems like they are able to 
convert an html file to mht. This works if access
 an html file from the web. But if you access the
 html file from your local drive then the 
conversion won't work. 

The above sources makes use of this method :
CreateMHTMLBody(URL, CDO.CdoMHTMLFlags.cdoSuppressNone, "", "");

Comment: The reason why i'm trying to embed image in html file
is because i'm creating a windows form application
that has to export a report with images.

Is there a way to accomplish without using commercial
libraries?

Comment: @chosenOneThabs the only way to do that without using commercial libraries is to implement the complete format (which is only partially documented) yourself.

Comment: Oh i finally decided to make use of Visual studio's ReportViewer Control, because i realized that this issue was going to take me some time to solve, and i'm having a deadline. But thanks alot, at least i learned about how MHT files work.

Answer (score 8):

In a Windows environment you can do this directly by means of the **CDO.Message** COM component, which exposes the [IMessage interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms526453%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)
I dont know the details of importing COM objects in C# so I'll give you a quick example in C-like syntax:

```
IMsgObj = CreateObject("CDO.Message")   // create the object
IMsgObj.CreateMHTMLBody("http://www.example.com/") // convert the URL to MHTML
IMsgObj.GetStream().SaveToFile("output.mht")  // save it to a file
```

The CLSID of the CDO.Message components is {CD000001-8B95-11D1-82DB-00C04FB1625D}

Keep in mind though, that this component is meant for generating e-mail messages (.eml file extension rather than .mht) which means JavaScript files are not included. Otherwise they are roughly equivalent.

Comment: *is valid for the html file from local drive?*

Comment: @Kiquenet, it should work. Just pass a file path instead of a URL

Answer (score 3):

[MSDN has a great article](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Creating-a-MHTML-MIME-HTML-61cf5dd1) (June 2011) about how to create an MHT file using both CDO and System.Net.Mail. C# source code is included in-full. I would use this above the VB.Net or Google Code version.

Comment: `Notes:` ***The main disadvantages of using CDO are:***
_COM Interop!_ and 
_Does not work in 64 bit systems (x64)_

Comment: `Notes:` *This sample (MSDN article) does not include code for handling css background images and iframes*

Answer (score 1):

I'd start with [RFC 2557](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2557) so that I had some basic understanding of what I was working with.  Then go look for [code/libraries](https://www.google.com/search?q=mime%20parser%20in%20c#) that deal with it.

To my knowledge there are no BCL classes to deal with MHTML.

Comment: I tried the above. It seems like they are able to 
convert an html file to mht. This works if access
 an html file from the web. But if you access the
 html file from your local drive then the 
conversion won't work. 

The above sources makes use of this method :
CreateMHTMLBody(URL, CDO.CdoMHTMLFlags.cdoSuppressNone, "", "");

Comment: The reason why i'm trying to embed image in html file
is because i'm creating a windows form application
that has to export a report with images.

Is there a way to accomplish without using commercial
libraries?

Comment: Create the report as a template. Export from ie. do search/replace to get report content in.

Comment: Oh i finally decided to make use of Visual studio's ReportViewer Control, because i realized that this issue was going to take me some time to solve, and i'm having a deadline. But thanks alot, at least i learned about how MHT files work.